# jquery remove row on click not working?

Tags: jquery

continue to tomorrows question

```
function n() {
  $('.m').on('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
    var p= $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();
    $('#c').append('<li class='li'>',id,<span class='c'>'"X"'</span>','</li>');
  });
} 
<style>
.c:hover
{
color:red;
}
.li
{
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.c',function()           
{

    $(this).closest("li").remove()
    alert("ok");
});

</script>
```

on clicking this 'X' symbol i want to delete that list,'OK' in alert printed but remove    function not working why?

Comment: There are lots of syntax error in your code. Please provide at least running code. I cannot tell if you really have those errors in your code or you are just sloppy copying your code here.

Comment: the style tag is not closed

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add the appropriate `script` and `style` tags within the markup.  They should also be closed appropriately, for example the `style` tag is unclosed.  The unclosed `style` tag could be causing problems.

Also within the `script` there are single quotes that are nested incorrectly.  Use outer single quotes to denote the string literal and double quotes within the string literal when required such as in markup.  It also appears you are attempting to concatenate using `,` however in Javascript the concatenation operator is `+`.

```
<script> <!-- I didn't exist />
function n() {
  $('.m').on('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
    var p= $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();

    //Concatenation and String literal fixed here
    $('#c').append('<li class="li">' + id + '<span class="c">X</span></li>');
  });
} 
</script>

<style>
    .c:hover
    {
        color:red;
    }

    .li
    {
    }
</style><!-- I wasn't closed -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.c',function()           
{

    $(this).closest("li").remove()
    alert("ok");
});

</script>
```

Comment: --ya here by mistakenly these syntax error,bt in my example it is properly written,but OK in alert is printed but list row not deleted  why?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten a semi colon after the remove() call

Comment: Semicolons are optional. There are situations where missing semicolons can lead to unexpected behavior, but this is not one of them.

Comment: So are car seat belts :-P ... true as that may be, if you're debugging this e.g. in an asp.net page using Visual Studio, chances are you're gonna have a head scratcher on your hands