# How to remove a cloned row

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a shopping cart. I've created a table containing products (each row contains an item, its price, and a button to select it). With js, when you click on a button of an item it clones the entire row of this item and put the clone in a second table (which is the shopping basket). I would like to remove a cloned row of the second table when clicking on its button. It's not about remove the DOM parent, because the button parent is a td and not the entire tr which I would like to delete.

```js
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.item_button');

for (button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', cloneLine);
}

function cloneLine(e) {
  let td = e.target.parentNode;
  let tr = td.parentNode;
  let clone = tr.cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);
  clone.querySelector('.item_button').textContent = "-";
}
```

```html
<h1>CHOOSE</h1>

<table id="starters">
  <tr>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>ADD TO CART</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cherry</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peach</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<h1>YOUR CHOICE</h1>

<table id="products_cart">

</table>
```

Comment: You can't delete the parent's parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove row on click not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942919/jquery-remove-row-on-click-not-working)

Comment: @Nordii I tried but it didn't work. But I'm not very confident with my syntax knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.item_button');

for (button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', cloneLine);
}

function cloneLine(e) {
  let td = e.target.parentNode;
  let tr = td.parentNode;
  let clone = tr.cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);
  clone.querySelector('.item_button').textContent = "-";
  clone.querySelector('.item_button').addEventListener("click", function(){    
    basket.removeChild(clone);
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>CHOOSE</h1>

<table id="starters">
  <tr>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>ADD TO CART</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cherry</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peach</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<h1>YOUR CHOICE</h1>

<table id="products_cart">

</table>
```